# passbook remind me at the specific time

Tags: ios, passbook

I use passbook with the following `pass.json`:

```
"formatVersion" : 1,
"passTypeIdentifier" : "pass.socialPoint.passbook",
"serialNumber" : "69874562241",
"teamIdentifier" : "9TS732CS23",
"lastUpdated" : "1357177440",
"associatedStoreIdentifiers":[564576004],
"relevantDate" : "2013-01-10T20:50+08:00",
"isRelative" : true,
"locations" : [{
  "longitude" : 128.598845,
  "latitude" : 35.203006
}],
```

and I want it to remind me at 20:50, but it doesn't. The time in the `pass.json` file is `2013-01-10T18:50+08:00`.

Comment: Can we see the integrated code?

Comment: passbook  is about  pass json,it is not code,because my pass format is correct,it can add to the passbook.apple can decide it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW53) (Table 3-2) the `relevantDate` key is not supported for `coupon` and `storeCard` passes.  Changing to one of the other Pass Types should allow your notification to display on the lock screen at the specified time.

Your notification time is set to 2013-01-10T18:50+08:00 which is 18:50 in China and 19:50 in Korea (which is where your location is).  Try setting as 2013-01-10T20:50+09:00

Comment: i modify : "eventTicket"  instead of storeCard not useful

Comment: You have locations in the pass so alert will trigger ONLY if location and time match

Comment: i want to location is match give a alert,or time match also give a alert.not ONLY if location and time match,can we do it?

Comment: Check the Docs, only `boardingPass` pass types support Relevant Data OR  Location alerts.